# Custom map style with ggmap

Tags: r, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ggmap

I have customized a style for use with `ggmap` using https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/. My question is how to integrate the JSON into my R code.

I tried the following code to no avail:

```
map <- get_googlemap(center = 'London', zoom = 15, 
                     style = c('element:labels|visibility:off', 'feature:road.local|visibility:off'))
ggmap(map)
```

It works with either of the style commands alone but not together. Where is the bug in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a package `ggmapstyles`, which should help with this problem: https://github.com/dr-harper/ggmapstyles

The package lets you select designs from [Snazzy Maps](https://snazzymaps.com/), and using the style from the page is as simple as copying the URL into the style:

```
devtools::install_github("mikey-harper/ggmapstyles")
library(ggmapstyles)

map <- get_snazzymap(center = 'London', 
                     mapRef = "https://snazzymaps.com/style/61/blue-essence")
ggmap(map)
```

[image]

If you don't find a design you like, you can join Snazzy Maps for free and make your own custom design within the web browser.

Comment: When trying to use `get_snazzymap`, I get a timeout error. I have a Google API and I have enabled geocoding and static maps. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the server was down previously, but seems to be back up and running. I want to update the package so that it caches some of the styles just in case this happens again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear myself on how exactly ggmap expects to receive styling, but `get_googlemap` has a parameter to inject a string into the URL sent to the Google Maps API. Based on the [Google Maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/), your strings seem formatted correctly for injecting. You can collapse each of those style specifications into a single string, and give that to the `inject` parameter rather than the `style` one.

So

`stylestr <- sprintf("&style=%s", c("element:labels|visibility:off", "feature:road.local|visibility:off") %>% paste(collapse = "")`

will yield the string `&style=element:labels|visibility:off&style=feature:road.local|visibility:off`

that can be used as your `inject` parameter. (I used `sprintf` and `paste` to make it easy for adding a whole slew of style specs.)