# Remove country and city names from map

Tags: r, ggmap

Using the `ggmap` package, I generate a map via

```
map <- get_map(location = c(10, 51), zoom = 6, maptype = "toner-lite", 
               scale = 1, color = "bw")
ggmap(map)
```

Is it possible to remove country and city names, as well as all boarders but the country ones?

Comment: `maptype = "toner-background"` looks like it might do what you want

Comment: Only by using different tiles. Each set of map tiles is fixed, so you can't change what's displayed. There are other tiles available from [Stamen](http://maps.stamen.com/#toner), or you can use a custom style in Google Maps. That second option is a little tricky, but there are a few posts on it, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43480986/5325862) one.

Comment: @Chris `"toner-background"` still shows roads, and I would prefer to have water not shown in black.

Comment: @camille There appears to be no Stamen tile set that achieves what I was looking for. I will look into Google Maps options.

Answer (score 2):

You can get reasonably close by changing the opacity of the `terrain-background` map and changing some of the theme elements in ggplot.

```
map <- get_map(location = c(10, 51), zoom = 6, maptype = "toner-background", 
               scale = 1, color = "bw")

# change opacity of basemap
mapatt <- attributes(map)
map_transparent <- matrix(adjustcolor(map, alpha.f = 0.2), nrow = nrow(map))
attributes(map_transparent) <- mapatt

ggmap(map_transparent) + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a billing-enabled Google Maps API key you can try:

[image: 1]

#### Code

```
map <- get_googlemap(c(10, 51), zoom = 6, scale = 1, style = s)
ggmap(map)
```

#### Data

```
s <- "element:geometry%7Ccolor:0xf5f5f5&style=element:labels%7Cvisibility:off&style=element:labels.icon%7Cvisibility:off&style=element:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x616161&style=element:labels.text.stroke%7Ccolor:0xf5f5f5&style=feature:administrative%7Celement:geometry%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:administrative.country%7Celement:geometry.stroke%7Ccolor:0x000000%7Cvisibility:on&style=feature:administrative.land_parcel%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:administrative.land_parcel%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0xbdbdbd&style=feature:administrative.neighborhood%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:poi%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:poi%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xeeeeee&style=feature:poi%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x757575&style=feature:poi.park%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xe5e5e5&style=feature:poi.park%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x9e9e9e&style=feature:road%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:road%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xffffff&style=feature:road%7Celement:labels.icon%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:road.arterial%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x757575&style=feature:road.highway%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xdadada&style=feature:road.highway%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x616161&style=feature:road.local%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x9e9e9e&style=feature:transit%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:transit.line%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xe5e5e5&style=feature:transit.station%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xeeeeee&style=feature:water%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xc9c9c9&style=feature:water%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x9e9e9e&size=480x360"
# Generated on https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/
```